# Unable to establish connection to http://controller:9696/v2.0/networks

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, openstack, openstack-neutron

I'm setting up openstack infrastructure, composed from controller and compute nodes.

I followed the process of setting sub-services as of USSURI version: keystone, glance, placement. See [article](https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/openstack-services.html)

When I came to neutron service, I started with setup of components hosted in controller node with option 1 (network provider) so I followed these 3 articles respectively : [process 1/3](https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/ussuri/install/controller-install-ubuntu.html)  -  [process 2/3](https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/ussuri/install/controller-install-option1-ubuntu.html)  -  [process 3/3](https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/launch-instance-networks-provider.html)

When I go to creating a network (process 3/3), I receive this error message :

```
$openstack network create --project-domain Default --project service --share --external --provider-physical-network provider --provider-network-type flat --enable provider

Unable to establish connection to http://controller:9696/v2.0/networks: HTTPConnectionPool(host='controller', port=9696): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2.0/networks (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd0a7c13630>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Waiting for help please.

---

**If the question helped, up-vote it. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Obviously your neutron service, which you created in process 2/3, is not up and running. Maybe you configured something wrong. Check the logs of your neutron-service, to find the exact reason, why its not running.

Comment: hello Tobias, please see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer...

Controller node Neutron setup process should stop at process 2/3, we can't move forward as this necessary command is not yet passed :

```
su -s /bin/sh -c "neutron-db-manage --config-file /etc/neutron/neutron.conf --config-file /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini upgrade head" neutron
```

It synchronizes Neutron databases and creates the necessary table for Neutron keystone-authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I taped these cmds :

```
# service neutron-server restart
# service neutron-linuxbridge-agent restart
# service neutron-dhcp-agent restart
# service neutron-metadata-agent restart
# service apache2 restart
```

before passing the cmd in question with debug option :

```
$ openstack network create --debug --project-domain Default --project service --share --external --provider-physical-network provider --provider-network-type flat --enable provider
```

but still coping with same issue:

```
keystoneauth1.exceptions.connection.ConnectFailure: Unable to establish connection to http://controller:9696/v2.0/networks: HTTPConnectionPool(host='controller', port=9696): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2.0/networks (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f1cc735e7f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Also I can see this line as debug output:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='controller', port=9696): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2.0/networks (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f1cc735e7f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Furthermore, I added this section to my conf file (/etc/neutron/neutron.conf):

```
[keystone_authtoken]
# ...
www_authenticate_uri = http://controller:5000
auth_url = http://controller:5000
memcached_servers = controller:11211
auth_type = password
project_domain_name = default
user_domain_name = default
project_name = service
username = neutron
password = XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: I had written you, that you should check the log-files of neutron. If it doesn't start because of a false configuration, it will crash again after you restarted it. The log-files can show you the reason, why it doesn't start.